# c++ one-line if/else syntax

Tags: c++, apache

This codesnippet confuses me:

```
/* First off, we need to check if this is a call for the "example-handler" handler.
 * If it is, we accept it and do our things, if not, we simply return DECLINED,
 * and the server will try somewhere else.
 */
if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler")) return (DECLINED);
```

[[Source]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/developer/modguide.html)

It says: "check if this is a call for the "example-handler" handler. **IF NOT, we simply return DECLINED**,"

I thought that "if (strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler")) return (DECLINED)" meant that if the string compare returns true, so if it is a call for the example-handler, DECLINED would be returned.

Comment: @drescherjm This is part of the example code from Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/developer/modguide.html

Comment: @drescherjm And certainly `r->handler != nullptr`.  Some authors like to obfuscate.

Comment: strcmp returns zero if the strings are equal, non-zero otherwise, so the code means that if the two strings are different return DECLINED.

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler")) return (DECLINED);
```

means

if r->handler is equal to NULL then return DECLINED

Or if r->handler is not equal to NULL but it contents is not equal to string literal "example-handler" then also return DECLINED

Standard C function `strcmp` returns 0 if both operands are equal to each other and non-zero value otherwise.

That expression

```
strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler") != 0
```

means that the operands are not equal each other.

From the C Standard

> The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, **equal to**, or
>   less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater
>   than, **equal to**, or less than the string pointed to by s2

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct. `strcmp` returns 0 if it is a match. Therefore you will continue on as the comment suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler")) return (DECLINED);
```

Can be rewritten more explicitly as:

```
if (r->handler == NULL /* or nullptr in C++11 */ || strcmp(r->handler, "example-handler") != 0) return (DECLINED);
```

Which basically means it returns DECLINED when:

1. handler is not provided
2. OR strcmp returns non-zero.

In strcmp's man pages, you can find out that strcmp returns non-zero when string do differ:

> The strcmp() function compares the two strings s1 and s2. It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

Comment: Or more correctly, `strcmp` doesn't return a `bool`, and so shouldn't be used in a context where a `bool` is expected.  The original code is pure obfuscation.